# Why does my timer stop after one second

Tags: c#

When I click a button that starts the timer whos interval is set to 1000ms it completes the code in the timer1_tick method once then nothing happens. It never reaches the else statement

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondsLeft = 20;
        if (secondsLeft > 0)
        {
            secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1;
            lbSecondsRemaining.Text = secondsLeft.ToString() + " seconds";
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Timer stopped");
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

The label lbSecondsRemaining changes to 19 and then nothing.

Comment: Just to note that you might want to change "secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1;" to "secondsLeft--;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you should take `secondsLeft = 20;` out of the method as it just sets `secondsLeft` to 20 everytime method fires.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (secondsLeft > 0)
        {
            secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1;
            lbSecondsRemaining.Text = secondsLeft.ToString() + " seconds";
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Timer stopped");
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondsLeft = 20;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```